# Plotting Date-Time VS (other variables Temperature, Humidity, Air Pressure)

Tags: r

```
        Date & Time Air-PSR   TEMP     HUM 
08/01/2014 00:13:00 961.471 31.282  63.008
08/01/2014 00:28:00 961.534 31.152  63.178
08/01/2014 00:43:00 961.559 31.036  63.336
08/01/2014 00:58:00 961.612 30.964  63.49
08/01/2014 01:13:00 961.46  30.883  63.642
08/01/2014 01:28:00 961.318 30.78   63.795
08/01/2014 01:43:00 961.39  30.697  63.943
08/01/2014 01:58:00 961.209 30.637  64.087
08/01/2014 02:13:00 961.172 30.578  64.23
08/01/2014 02:43:00 961.679 30.486  64.521
08/01/2014 02:58:00 961.342 30.32   64.695
08/01/2014 03:13:00 961.214 30.052  64.878
08/01/2014 03:28:00 961.5   29.839  65.056
08/01/2014 03:43:00 961.541 29.689  65.231
08/01/2014 03:58:00 961.796 29.576  65.405
08/01/2014 04:13:00 962.027 29.472  65.577
08/01/2014 04:28:00 962.469 29.407  65.748
08/01/2014 04:43:00 962.909 29.25   65.961
08/01/2014 04:58:00 962.313 29.004  66.171
```

I have done the following for plotting of this data set:

```
temp <- read.csv("test_imp_DT.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
temp
class(temp$DT) # it gives character
class(temp$RS) # it gives inteeger
as.POSIXct(strptime(temp$DT, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) # converting character to date and time
```

After running the above code I got the error in the form of `NA`. All the data has been converted to `NA`

Alternative method:

```
temp[i]$DT = as.POSIXct(temp[i]$DT,format="%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S")
plot(temp[i]$DT~temp[i]$RS,na.rm=TRUE),data=temp[i],type='l',col='red')
```

I get this error:

> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values

And when I changed it for y-limit also get the error i.e.

```
plot(temp[i]$DT~temp[i]$RS,y = range(temp[i]$RS, na.rm=TRUE),data=temp[i],type='l',col='red')
```

In the simplest way I just want to make a graph of Date-Time VS Temperature, Date-Time VS Humidity and Date-Time VS Air Pressure for the above given sample data file.

[image]

Also at second stage I want to make separate graph for weekly basis, since I have the data set of 4 months.

Comment: the data can be found at the following link:

Comment: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` this is clearly not the format your date-times are in. Correct this.

Comment: Dear Ronald, please suggest some code that I will run to get the correct form of the data... Also the above graph that was shown in the question was obtained from MS-Excel. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Study `help("strptime")` to understand how the `format` string works. However, it should be pretty self-explaining.

Comment: Thanks Ronald, I will run and let you know in the comments.

Comment: Dear Ronald this is the command that I used but get the NA's only:   temp$DT <- as.POSIXct(strptime(temp$DT, "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y"))

Comment: I have no idea how you could believe that to be correct after reading the documentation. (Btw. my name is not Ronald.)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of doing this is by using the package [*lubridate*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html). I cannot see the link to your data, so I will show just an example of the conversion you are interested in:

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hms("08/01/2014 00:13:00")
[1] "2014-01-08 00:13:00 UTC"
```

Following up on your questions, to convert a variable in a dataframe you apply
the function to the entire column, for example:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c("08/01/2014 00:13:00", "08/01/2015 00:13:00", "08/02/2015 00:13:00")
df <- data.frame(x,y, stringsAsFactors = F)
df
 x                   y
1 1 08/01/2014 00:13:00
2 2 08/01/2015 00:13:00
3 3 08/02/2015 00:13:00
class(df$y)
[1] "character"
df$y <- dmy_hms(df$y)
class(df$y)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dear thepule for your guidance. When I was uploading the question at this forum, I didn't see the data but now it is showing in the above section in the proper format. Thanks for your guidance. Now after using the lubridate how I can apply it only my "Date and Time" variable for the data matrix which is also containing some other variables. I mean using this commanad: temp$DT<- dmy_hms(temp$DT)   Is it?

Comment: The answer you provided is working only for single value, If I want to use it for complete vector then how the the task will be perform? Thanks for reply

Comment: @Zeeshan, yes using temp$DT<- dmy_hms(temp$DT) will convert the entire column. See the update to my original answer above.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind guidance and helping me. I will run the results and inform you.

Comment: Dear Thepule when I run this command: df$y <- dmy_hms(df$y); I get the warning message: "Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found"... But the next command class(df$y) works perfectely... Why I get the warning message..? Is it working properly? Please give your valuable suggestion and comments